# I want to record using an excel using loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to record the requests while interacting with my server using an excel where it sends http request to the server. I have been using oracle openscript where i could easily configure my server name and the port it works on. Is there a way to do the same in loadrunner?

Answer (score 0):

Record using Proxy Mode.   The LR HTTP recording proxy will act as a man-in-the-middle for your connection from Excel to it's back end data source.  Excel and the recording proxy need not be on the same host.

Answer (score 0):

You can record in LoadRunner using **Web - HTTP/HTML** protocol. Within this protocol, you have got 2 options to utilize:

1. Record Windows Application.
2. LoadRunner Proxy Recording.

**1. Record Windows Application**:
Provide the path to the excel.exe and then start recording.

**2. LoadRunner Proxy Recording**: 
Set a listening port for LoadRunner and then force Excel to send requests to the servers via this particular port.